# Why do the apps written in java run only on android, even if java is platform independent

Tags: java, android

Years ago I studied core java in that I read that one of the features of java is that it is platform independent.
Reference: https://www.javatpoint.com/features-of-java

Now I am working on android development, android apps are developed using core java. Then why is it that those apps are not supported in Windowsphone or ios?

Comment: cause android programming uses google apis that are available only for android

Comment: Android is different from Java. The compliing process of android is different then java.

Comment: Java is said to be platform independent because of the JVM, but Android does not use the JVM. They use something called Dalvik or whatever...

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/

Comment: @Sweeper as of android 5 they use the art runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java the code is first compiled into byte code. This byte code is platform independent.This code is executed in JVM. JVM is part of JRE. JRE is different for every platform. You need to download and install JRE according to your platform, Windows or Linux.

Android does not use JVM. The compiled byte code is converted Dex byte code which runs on DVM. DVM only exists for Android as of now. So code written for Android cannot run on other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Android development uses Java as one of its primary development languages. There are other languages also that you can use to develop apps for Android. For example, [Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/index.html) was recently added to this set of languages.

When you compile the code that your wrote for an Android app, it is converted into byte code that is suitable for the Android VM ([Dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software))) but not for Java's own JVM.

This provides and advantage to the Android platform that a developer does not have to learn a whole new language to develop apps for Android. No matter which programming language you know, you can develop apps for Android and when you compile the code, it converts code from any of these supported languages into the same byte code which can run on the Android VM.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are different,

Android API is not Java API, but just copying most of its features, please take a look in the detail with the following links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API